# While importing KML/KMZ rasters only colourful rectangles appear, although in right places

Tags: raster, kml, mac, kmz

I'm trying to load KMZ rasters (file [here](https://shh-cloud.gnz.mpg.de/index.php/s/6HgyRsf5XaFdBzf)) from Google Earth, but they are imported as mono-colour rectangles. They are in the right places though.

[image: rectangulars instead of rasters]

Global Mapper is suggested as a solution elsewhere ([268166](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268166/importing-kmz-kml-into-qgis-as-raster/366746?noredirect=1#comment600348_366746)) but is not available for macOS.

Comment: Rename the kmz to zip and extract - the rasters are .png (there are 53 images) - if you need to do this on a mac use kmz>rar extractor https://gist.github.com/I82Much/959880

Comment: But these images .png won't be georeferenced. Georeference data is in .kmz (in doc.kml).

Comment: you can extract the coordinates from the kml and create a .pngw (globalmapper will read it).

Comment: True, but (1) there are dozens of files and (2) as I mentioned above, Global Mapper doesn't run on Mac (I don't feel like installing virtual desktop just to convert some files).

I hope there is another solution.

Comment: Globalmapper will run via parallels or a VM, but not nativity on Mac OS. The whole process can be done in python which can be run in the Mac OS environment.